# Infragistics ,webtab selectedindexchanged not firing when i change the tabs

Tags: infragistics

I am using Infragistics WebTab Control ,which has 3 tabs on change of tab  the selectedindexchanged event is not firing .I have tried solutions on the Infragistics forum ,but they are not working .One of the solution was to add this code to the WebTab control

EnableReloadingUnselectedTab="true" EnableAjax="true" EnableLoadOnDemand="false" 
but still the event is not firing

My ASPX page code is :

```
    <ig:WebTab ID="tbEpip" runat="server" Height="279px" Width="726px" 
                    EnableReloadingUnselectedTab="true" EnableAjax="true" EnableLoadOnDemand="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "tbEpip_SelectedIndexChanged"
>
                    <Tabs>
                        <ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" Text="Data Download">


  </ig:ContentTabItem>
                        <ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" Text="Data Upload">
                            <Template>
                                <table class="ControlUltraTab" style="width:100%" >

 </ig:ContentTabItem>
                        <ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" Text="Memo Generation">
                            <Template>
```

My VB code is :

```
  Protected Sub tbEpip_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As Infragistics.Web.UI.LayoutControls.TabSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles tbEpip.SelectedIndexChanged


 End Sub
```